Flutter Timer.periodic() on iOS only fires once
Flutter app running on iPad. App is always on screen, but can go with no user interaction or background code activity for long. It may run in regular, or iOS Guided mode.
I have a periodic trigger in initState() of my widget. this is the widget called by .runApp(). no timer.cancel() ever called.
Judging by logs, it triggers once, exactly one hour after launch. But subsequently - nothing.

something wrong with code?
if not, why isnt it triggered each hour?
what's recommended way of doing something like this? background isolate? workmanager?

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
...
    Timer.periodic(
      const Duration(hours: 1),
      (timer) => runHourlyMaintenance(),
    );

...


if the app stays in the foreground, doesn't it trigger then too?

Is the app running in the foreground the entire time with the device staying awake?

@Thomas
yes,

app is in foreground all the time,
device is always awake, lock is on infinite, screen is always on

still, callback only triggered once.

@Abion47 pls see above ^^^

uhm, shouldn't you assign Timer().periodic to some property? I think what happens is that it gets immediately disposed when initstate is left?

@Thomas That shouldn't be necessary. Timer objects get registered and will be automatically referenced.  That's why it's important to explicitly call Timer.cancel when they're no longer necessary.

@jamesdlin are you sure? I know it works for streams. But I'm not sure if this is the case with a Timer.

I agree with @jamesdlin, from doc too it looks like scope/lifetime is handled inside Timer class https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html

@Thomas Yes, I'm sure.  Creating a periodic Timer in initState, neglecting to keep a reference to it so that it can be cancelled in dispose, and then ending up with multiple, active periodic Timers is a pretty common problem.

Yeah, you are right, the passed in lambda prevents the GC from disposing it. Only other explanation then I can imagine then is that your hourlyMaintanance() function throws an exception. Alternatively you could try if Stream.periodic behaves the same.

Does that only happen on iOS?

Does this happen too if you chose a shorter interval?

@Thomas so far only tested on iOS. I plan to test with shorter intervals next.

It's really puzzling. One thing I could imagine is that iOS somehow pauses apps that aren't doing any serious processing for a long time. What you describe is against everything I have seen so far.

False alarm all, on me. A perfect storm of hidden exception, disappearing logs and whatnot. Timer.periodic() cleared of all charges, trusted friend once again. Happy ending.
